# Sculpting tool wont work for any object that I place

Tags: scripting, 3d-view

[image]

The starting object I can sculpt, all others I can’t, I don’t understand why.

I have seen the thread where it explained that the clip end should not be set to infinite, and it even had a nice picture. I can not find that setting so, if that is how to fix this, please instructed me click by click how to find it.

Comment: Hello and welcome. It is unclear what you are asking. Please use the [edit] link at the 
bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add 
more information on how you set up your project.
[Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that 
might help us understand your scene and settings. See [How to upload 
an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491).

Comment: First of all, you can't sculpt if you are selecting mulple object, second, also not gonna work if you have a camera and light selected. You need to combine all the objects (Mesh only) into one single mesh (CTRL + J)

Comment: Only the active object can be edited in scuplt mode. In your screenshot it´s Cylinder.001. Highlighted in the outliner and with a sculptmode icon to the left. Other objects are locked, marked by red text in outliner and red borders in 3D Viewport. To change the active object in sculpt mode, click the dot to the left of an inactive object in Outliner.

Answer (score 1):

There are some rules you need to follow as to sculpt an object.

1. In order to sculpt the body of your object as it is on your picture you have to make all the objects one.
2. Then there is the problem that every ball and arm, although now they are one object, their previous geometry as a whole has nothing to do with one item's geometry. When you sculpt an object and manipulate the vertices of the object, every vertex is connected to another and that is what makes an item's vertices/geometry.
   Here even after <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> to merge all single objects the geometry of the produced single object isn't interconnected.
3. Sculpting works with a single object with enough geometry(concentrated vertices) to see the change when you sculpt. You can sculpt every single object but if your geometry (low number of vertices) can't show any difference then it looks like sculpting is not working.

To finish the answer to do what you want here just make a single (not many different) object with a lot of vertices and then start sculpting. You will start to see how it works.

Remember you can always make a low poly object and add geometry until you can sculpt it.